# Query a single column from Room database and calculate the sum

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to query my database, to get all the data from one column.

This information is a string, for example "19,96 €" (I can delete the € if needed of course)

I need a function that converts this column's data into a double and returns the sum for me to display in another view.
I think i have the query already, but I am not sure.

How would I go on now? How do i turn the column into a double and get the sum out of it?

Here is the Itemclass:

```
 @Entity(tableName = "receipt_table")
 @Parcelize
 data class Receipts(
@ColumnInfo(name = "total") var total: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "store") var store: String,
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int= 0) : Parcelable
```

And the Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ReceiptDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM receipt_table")
    fun getAllReceipts(): Flow<List<Receipts>>

    @Query("SELECT total FROM receipt_table")
    fun getAllReceiptsTotal(): Flow<List<Int>>

    ///@Query("SELECT date FROM receipt_table")
    ///fun getDate(): Flow<List<Receipts>>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(receipts: Receipts)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(receipts: Receipts)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(receipts: Receipts)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A query that does what you want is this:

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(total, ',', '.')) AS sum_total 
FROM receipt_table
```

The currency suffix `€` is not a problem, but the decimal separator `,` is and with `REPLACE()` it is changed to a `.`.
Then SQLite implicitly converts the values of the column to numeric values in order to perform the aggregation.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7879c0eba519e81dfb0bb9f36128faa9).

Note that it is better to store numeric values as numbers and not strings.

Comment: thanks alot! So the code i would use would be:
@Query("SELECT SUM(REPLACE(total, ',', '.')) AS sum_total 
FROM receipt_table") ?

Comment: @dkiwikid yes, like any other query.

Comment: Alright, first time using something like a database so sorry for those questions. 
The function to access it somewhere else in my programm stays the same tho right? 
fun getAllReceiptsTotal(): Flow<List<String>> or how else do I get access to the data that i just queryd?